# Firefox: How to open tabs in specific windows, depending on the URL?

Tags: firefox, browser, browser-tabs

Is there a convenient way to have two windows of Firefox and keep them 'organized' in that way, that when you open links, the tabs go to one windows if of specific domain, and the other (or any) if not?

I currently have one single window, and few tabs for mail, calendar, chat etc., some browser based office applications, and they are mixed of course with other tabs I browse.

I could have a separate FF window for the 'office apps', but when clicking on a link e.g. in a mail, it should not open in the 'office' window, but any other window.

Is there maybe an add-on with a configurable URL-filter doing this?

Answer (score 2):

One possibility: https://gitlab.com/juszczakn/other-win

It's manual, but when right-clicking on a link, you can send it to the other window, keeping that window clean with just the wanted tabs.

Comment: Good find!  I tried it, and it worked well.